# Java - Simple formatting regarding power of 2 triangle

Tags: java

**Overview**

I'm sure this is a simple problem for most of you on here, but I have been struggling with a small spacing problem and was hoping I can learn from someone more experienced. I need to produce a triangle similar to the one below. You can see that the numbers are aligned correctly no matter the length.

```
Enter the number of lines: 8
                               1                            
                           1   2   1                        
                       1   2   4   2   1                    
                   1   2   4   8   4   2   1                
               1   2   4   8  16   8   4   2   1            
           1   2   4   8  16  32  16   8   4   2   1        
       1   2   4   8  16  32  64  32  16   8   4   2   1    
   1   2   4   8  16  32  64 128  64  32  16   8   4   2   1
```

**My Code**

Here is what I have so far. It isn't the prettiest, but it seems to give me the correct values at least.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Pyramid2
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int i, j, k, l, a;

        //Create a Scanner object
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);

        //Prompt the user to enter number of rows in pyramid
        System.out.print("Enter number of rows: ");
        int rows = in.nextInt();
        a = rows;

        //Variables to determine length
        int length = ("" + rows).length();
        String str = " %" + length + "s";

        //Logic
        for (i = 1; i <= rows; i++)
        {
            for (j = a; j > 0; j--)
            {
                System.out.printf(str, " ");
            }

            for (j = 1; j <= (2*rows); j++)
            {
                if (j == (rows+1))
                {
                    continue;
                }

                if (j < (rows+1))
                {
                    k = j;
                }
                else
                {
                    k = ((2*rows)-j+1);
                }

                if (k >= (rows+1-i))
                {
                    l = (int)Math.pow(2, (i+k-rows-1));
                    String str1 = "" + l;
                    System.out.printf(str, str1);
                }
            }
            a--;
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

**My Results**

This is the console output when 6 rows are chosen. Everything looks good until row 5 when a 2 digit number (16) appears. What are some efficient ways to align the results properly?

```
Enter number of rows: 6
             1
           1 2 1
         1 2 4 2 1
       1 2 4 8 4 2 1
     1 2 4 8 16 8 4 2 1
   1 2 4 8 16 32 16 8 4 2 1
```

Comment: Instead of printing 1 space after each number, print `maxNumberOfDigits - numberOfDigits(number) + 1` spaces. --- maxNumberOfDigits is 2 in this case. The pyramid will be wider, but it won't misalign. You can use nCr calculation to find the maxNumberOfDigits

Comment: You could use "\t" instead of space in your System.out.printf statement to produce a tabulation.

Comment: Some general advice: 1: choose meaningful names for your variables. 2: avoid unnecessary statements, such as `String str1` = "" + l;` as you can use `l` directly in the `printf` call.

Comment: @Dukeling In what way is question too broad or unclear? It is a good [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), since it has all relevant code to reproduce the problem, and show both expected and actual output. Very "complete" and "verifiable". What more do you want? The "minimal" part? The code is not that large.

Comment: @Andreas It's not what I would call an MCVE because it's just a program dump with no debugging, which has limited to no future value as a result of that. The ideal sequence of events (in my opinion) would've been for OP to do some [**debugging**](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) to figure out where the problem lies, and then look at the desired output to figure out the desired behaviour, and then maybe ask a question about that they got stuck (which seems unlikely if the problem is broken down appropriately, based on the knowledge demonstrated in the code).

Comment: @Dukeling If you want to suggest to OP that some debugging would be good, go ahead. I'm just saying that question should not be closed as "too broad" or "unclear", since it is neither. It has a very nice MCVE, and clearly shows the issue. It is certainly not "too broad", since it has a *"specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer"*, and the [answer is simple](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48464889/5221149).

Comment: @Dukeling I agree that debugging is a great tool, and I will be sure to use this moving forward as I continue to learn. However, I took the time to be as concise, clear and direct as possible. I came to the table with a very specific spacing issue which I felt I did an effective job of communicating. For these reasons I don't understand how this question can be classified as "too broad". I hope that in the future you support new members posting such clear examples because I have certainly seen much worse than mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You calculate `length` as the number of digits in `rows`, but it needs to be number of digits in largest number in triangle.

E.g. for `rows = 6`, largest number is `32`, so `length` should be `2`.
For `rows = 8`, largest number is `128`, so `length` should be `3`.

Largest number is 2<sup>rows</sup>, which in Java means `1 << rows`, so change `length` calculation to:

```
int length = ("" + (1 << rows)).length();
```

---

You are also adding one too many blanks on the left.

Change code to this:

```
a = rows - 1;
```

Comment: `int length = Integer.ToString(1 << rows).length();` is better I think.

Comment: @martijnn2008 It's not, because that method doesn't exist. `toString` does, but not really better for this code, since performance is a non-issue.

Comment: You don't even need to convert the number into a string representation, since we know that it's a base 10 representation. You can use (pseudocode) `int(log10(2**i)) + 1` which in turn is `int(i * ln(2) / ln(10)) + 1` instead, avoiding exponentiation and creating a String ;)

Comment: @Tedil Avoiding exponentiation at the cost of two logarithm calls? How is that an improvement? And why go through `double` calculations for something that a simple string `length()` can tell us. This is not code that has *any* issues with performance or memory footprint. Using `("" + x).length()` is perfectly fine for this code. It clearly shows the *intent* of the code, so it's actually better here than some obscure math calculation. It is also the smallest change to fix OP's code. This is https://stackoverflow.com/, not https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Andreas yes, I agree completely.  I didn't post that comment to address nonexistent performance or clarity issues, but rather to point out the math behind that ;) (also note that ln(2)/ln(10) is constant, so practically no log calls needed there)

Comment: @Andreas Thank you very much for your time and effort. This was extremely helpful. I sincerely appreciate how you didn't only include the fix, but took the time to teach me why an issue was occurring then demonstrated how the solution works. I now clearly understand my errors. Have a great day!

Answer (score 3):

First of all i can recommend to determine the largest number in pyramid. Then count digits in this number. For 8 rows this number is 128, it has 3 digits. According this information we can decide that we need 3+1=4 (including spaces) characters to print every value in pyramid.
After it you have to complete every output number by spaces (from the left) to achive string size of 4 characters.
And the global prefix for every pyramid line will contain (rows - i) * 4 spaces.